# Database Table in SQL Server

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql-server, database-design

I have an excel table. I created a database table in SQL Server database platform in ArcMap. I added fields, fields' data type, and domains to some data fields (columns). When I open the table, all I see is just a table with field names only.

Can I not view the database table in SQL Server in ArcGIS desktop?

Also, how can I populate rest of my records ( rows) in the table?

Comment: Can you view the empty table in ArcCatalog?  If so, you may be able to just right click on the table and select Load>Load Data option to copy over the records.